# joining two streams of observables in RxJs according to specific conditions

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive-programming, rxjs5

I have two streams of objects, the accounts and balances.

I need to merge (join) the two streams according to the `id` and `account_id`

```
var accounts = Rx.Observable.from([
    { id: 1, name: 'account 1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'account 2' },
    { id: 3, name: 'account 3' },
]);

var balances = Rx.Observable.from([
    { account_id: 1, balance: 100 },
    { account_id: 2, balance: 200 },
    { account_id: 3, balance: 300 },
]);
```

What is expected:

```
var results = [
    { id: 1, name: 'account 1', balance: 100},
    { id: 2, name: 'account 2', balance: 200},
    { id: 3, name: 'account 3', balance: 300},
];
```

Is this feasible with RxJs ?

To be clear I know how to do this with plain js/lodash or something similar. In my case I am getting these streams from Angular Http Module, so I am asking If I could get benefit of RxJs in this case

Comment: Do you want the result once both streams have ended or build them over time ?

Comment: If you would post a sample code, it would help understand better the question. As presented, it is not clear why you dont make the join directly on the arrays instead of doing it from within the stream. But anyways, yes it is possible to do the join you mention. Cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43332674/rxjs-to-combine-attributes-from-triples-to-a-table/43333630#43333630 which shows how to iteratively build a structure

Comment: @Maxime, In my case after completion, but If there is a way to do it during the flow it will be good also

Comment: @user3743222, thanks for the suggestion, however I simplified the question to what needed exactly. the reason is simply I am getting the results as a stream from the Angular HttpModule

Answer (score 3):

Accoring to one of your comment, your example is to simulate a stream from an Angular Http call.

So instead of :

```
var accounts = Rx.Observable.from([
    { id: 1, name: 'account 1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'account 2' },
    { id: 3, name: 'account 3' },
]);

var balances = Rx.Observable.from([
    { account_id: 1, balance: 100 },
    { account_id: 2, balance: 200 },
    { account_id: 3, balance: 300 },
]);
```

I'd rather say that it is :

```
var accounts = Rx.Observable.of([
    { id: 1, name: 'account 1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'account 2' },
    { id: 3, name: 'account 3' },
]);

var balances = Rx.Observable.of([
    { account_id: 1, balance: 100 },
    { account_id: 2, balance: 200 },
    { account_id: 3, balance: 300 },
]);
```

**Why :** `from` will emit every item one by one, `of` will emit the entire array and I guess your http response is the whole array.

**That said, what you probably want to achieve is :**

```
const { Observable } = Rx;

// simulate HTTP requests
const accounts$ = Rx.Observable.of([
  { id: 1, name: 'account 1' },
  { id: 2, name: 'account 2' },
  { id: 3, name: 'account 3' }
]);

const balances$ = Rx.Observable.of([
  { account_id: 1, balance: 100 },
  { account_id: 2, balance: 200 },
  { account_id: 3, balance: 300 }
]);

// utils
const joinArrays = (accounts, balances) =>
  accounts
    .map(account => Object.assign({}, account, { balance: findBalanceByAccountId(balances, account.id).balance }));

const findBalanceByAccountId = (balances, id) =>
  balances.find(balance => balance.account_id === id) || { balance: 0 };

const print = (obj) => JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2)

// use forkJoin to start both observables at the same time and not wait between every request
Observable
  .forkJoin(accounts$, balances$)
  .map(([accounts, balances]) => joinArrays(accounts, balances))
  .do(rslt => console.log(print(rslt)))
  .subscribe();
```

**Output :**

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "account 1",
    "balance": 100
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "account 2",
    "balance": 200
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "account 3",
    "balance": 300
  }
]
```

Here's a working Plunkr : https://plnkr.co/edit/bc0YHrISu3FT45ftIFwz?p=preview

**EDIT 1 :**
Working on an array to compose your result is probably not the best idea for performance and instead of returning an array, maybe try to return an object which have as key, the ID of the account. This way you might simply remove the `findBalanceByAccountId` function and have a faster app *(only modified code here)* :

```
const balances$ = Rx.Observable.of({
  1: { account_id: 1, balance: 100 },
  2: { account_id: 2, balance: 200 },
  3: { account_id: 3, balance: 300 }
});

// utils
const joinArrays = (accounts, balances) =>
  accounts
    .map(account => Object.assign(
      {}, 
      account, 
      { balance: balances[account.id].balance }
    ));
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately your assumption is not correct :s, actually I have the data as stream of objects `Observable<Account>` and not a stream of single array `Observable<Account[]>`

Answer (score 0):

If you have truly 2 observables that emit the results as `Observable<{}>` in random order, this is a way you can combine them. If the order is not random, or if they always come in 'pairs', more efficient way's exists to combine them.

```
import { from, merge } from 'rxjs';
import { map, scan, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

const accounts = from([
  { id: 1, name: 'account 1' },
  { id: 2, name: 'account 2' },
  { id: 3, name: 'account 3' }
]);

const balances = from([
  { account_id: 1, balance: 100 },
  { account_id: 2, balance: 200 },
  { account_id: 3, balance: 300 }
]);

interface Outcome {
  id: number;
  name?: string;
  balance?: number;
}

merge<Outcome>(
  accounts,
  balances.pipe(map(a => ({ id: a.account_id, balance: a.balance })))
)
  .pipe(
    scan<Outcome>((result: Outcome[], incomming) => {
        const found = result.find(row => row.id === incomming.id);
        if (found) {
          Object.assign(found, incomming);
        } else {
          result.push(incomming);
        }
      return result;
    }, []),
    tap(r => console.log(r))
  )
  .subscribe();
```

Please note that the result is a hot observable. If you only want to emit a single result and complete when all results are in, replace the `scan` operator with the `reduce` operator.

The source is based on RXjs version 6. your imports might differ a bit on older versions.