# Angular: trying to perform nested subscription

Tags: angular, api, nested

I am very new to Angular and trying to get my head around so many concepts.  I have an observable that correctly gets an array of json objects back from an api.  The problem is that for each member of the array I need to call a second api to get back a single value (side note - I will limit the return of the first api call to 6 members).  I then want to store that single value into each member of the array as a new property. The call to the first api returns a value that I will need to query a second api to get the value that I want to store.

I found several example of how to do this but I am still struggling a little bit.  Part of the problem is that I am using an interface "Movies" and that is tripping me up (I think).  [This](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/handle-multiple-api-requests-in-angular-using-mergemap-and-forkjoin-to-avoid-nested-subscriptions-a20fb5040d0c) is pretty close to what I want to do.  Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

```
public getMovies(): Observable<Movie[]>
  {
    return this.http.get<Movie[]>(this.apiUrl, this.httpOptions).pipe(
      tap(data => console.log( data[0].movie.ids['imdb'])),    // this works.  I need to pass this into a second service
       catchError (this.handleError)
      );
      // mergeMap ( data => this.http.get (someAPI ?id= {data[0].movie.ids['imdb']} )) //make call here?
.subscribe ( data => {
   // not sure about this.  I need to store the return of the second call into Movie property.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think It should be do it separated, because Imagine you have an array of 1000 movies you will do 1k of http request.

Then I sugest you need to fetch all the movies and show them and when the user clicks each movie, fetch the new api that i supouse its the movie description (actors, sipnosis, etc).

```
public getMovies(): Observable<Movie[]>
{
     return this.http.get<Movie[]>(this.apiUrl, this.httpOptions);
}

public getMovieDescription(movieId): Observable<MovieDescription>
{
     //Use the Movie Id to fecth the movie description
     return this.http.get<MovieDescription>(this.apiUrl, this.httpOptions);
}
```

take a look to this example 
[joining two streams of observables in RxJs according to specific conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43602770/joining-two-streams-of-observables-in-rxjs-according-to-specific-conditions)

Comment: Thanks Abel.  As I said previously I am only getting 6 movies in the original call so I don't see why I couldn't nest them.  The vast majority of the items for the movie arrive from the first call - I just need one more item from the second call to complete the array.

Comment: Ok, Then keep  this code in you service (using two separed methods), and in the component  call the  getMovies() using a subscribe  when you get the results  perform a for each  and  call the second getMovieDescription using the movie Id. I will modify the example, even though it is not a good aproach it looks like you want to do  a inner join in the client side.

Comment: I add a reference answer  i hope it could help you

Comment: Thanks again Abel, I really appreciate it.  But I think we are back to my original question.  I know how to phrase the second api call in the inner observable.  I am having a hard time phrasing it in the code.  Also, I don't know how to put the value back in the original array.  The example that you provided was for joining two similar arrays and that's not what I am looking to do here.